# Why does Cave's Black Label sometimes add extra attacks?

Tags: hyperdimension-neptunia-mk2

Cave's Black Label seems to have 3(?) separate parts: A main attack which showers bullet-hell style bullets on targets, and two second parts which involve "Option" style bee-things which shoot more bullets, then lasers. I've seen her perform the first part alone, and I *think* I've seen her only perform half of the "bee" related attacks on a separate occasion.

At first I thought she stopped attacking once the targets died, as I had only seen the full attack against bosses. But later I tried the attack against a tough normal target and only the first bullet hell style attack triggered. What determines how many stages of the attack I'll get? Is it random or based on the target's boss status or based on something else entirely?

It seems Falcom's Moon Dragon acts in much the same way as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every character has an "ultimate" skill, although the majority of them only are available from the (free) DLC. These would be things like Nepgear's Celestial Severance, Neptune's Neptune Break, and in this case Cave's Black Label. They all cost 150 SP, so it's easy to know which one it is (although CPUs and CPU candidates have reduced SP cost in HDD).

These skills that are so expensive you can't even stock up enough base SP to use, have a "finisher" that is added whenever you use it against what is counted as a boss (which, in mk2's case, is just story bosses). The finisher not only looks flashier but adds a decent amount of extra damage to the attack.